# Datetime Handling issue with Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, error-handling

I'm having a column and its original dtype is object. I'm trying to convert it to datetime by using pd.to_datetime. However, it gives me an error like this: "time data '3/30/2023' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (match)". I checked on the error but could not understand how my format doesn't match the data itself. Could you please help me with the error?

This is my original data:

```
print(df['Start time'])

>>> 3/30/2023 22:24
```

and this is my code for converting it

```
df['Start time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start time'], format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

However, it returned this error
`ValueError: time data '3/30/2023' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (match)`

Comment: `'3/30/2023'` ≠ `'3/30/2023 22:24'`, don't use a fixed format but `dayfirst=False`